# py file in blender wont show its line breaks

Tags: python, text-editor

I ran into a strange issue and could need some help. A Javascript file writes a python file, that I can use in blender to setup and animate my scene. everything works fine, and as expected on Windows. Now it turns out that if I run the Javascript on MAC, then the python file, that's been written cannot be run in blender. Because the python file wont have line breaks. Strangely though it shows the Linebreaks of that exact file in all other text editors (Notepad, Wordpad, Chrome browser, sublime text, etc.) The javascriptfile is writing linebreaks with `\n`, and from what I read this should be fine with linus and macOs.Is `\n` the proper code?

Now my workaround would be to use `;` at the end of each line, but how would I code the end of a for loop, without using unindents of a new line?

Another workaround would be to quit the for loop, and let each for cycle be written explicitly, (without the need of indents)

But I really would appreciate a solution that keeps the code simple. I really would like to understand why blender loses linebreaks `\n` when the py is created on macOS.

Same Python file in Sublime/Wordpad and Blender:
[image]

Comment: can you provide the javascript file (or just a part) via a cloudservice so we can check it out?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599936/handling-r-n-vs-n-newlines-in-python-on-mac-vs-windows

Comment: thanks gunslinger that almost worked, its describing the exact same situation: the file wont work on mac due to linebreaks. unfortunately the proposed \r\n results in the same "one line-all code" formatting as with \n. this didnt solve the problem.

Comment: Did you save the files, using an editor or did the script save the file directly?

Comment: notepad++ tells me, \r would be the correct line break for mac

Comment: @AndréZmuda Old Macs used \r but they've been \n for about 20 years now.

Comment: @scurest   :-)  -  good to know.

Comment: @AndéZmuda the javascript runs in after effects and writes (saves) the python file.